# integral over a region boundary

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex, regions, computational-geometry

I want to integrate a complex function over a boundary of a region:

$$-\frac{i}{v}\oint_\Gamma \exp(-2\pi i(ux+vy))\,dx,$$

where $\Gamma$ is the closed boundary of a region and $y = f(x)$.

I know that MMA can extract the boundary of a region. For instance:

```
R = RegionBoundary[Disk[]];
```

returns the circumference of the unit circle. Therefore if I do:

```
Integrate[1, {x, y} ∈ R]
```

gives its length: $2\pi$.

No problem thus far as I understanding that the integral is a contour integral. I mean, it is integrating over the boundary of the region R.

Now, if I do the following:

```
Assuming[v >= 0 && u >= 0, -I/v*Integrate[Exp[-2 π I (u*x + v*y)], {x, y} ∈ R] // FunctionExpand]
```

it should return:

```
2 π BesselJ[1, 2 π Sqrt[u^2 + v^2]]/Sqrt[u^2 + v^2]
```

but it doesn't.

Am I not understanding correctly how to extract the boundary of a region to use it in a integral along that contour?, or am I not doing the integration well?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: If I place the `FunctionExpand` *outside* of integral, I get an answer in terms of `BesselJ`.

Comment: @ChipHurst you mean you obtain exactly what I am expecting?

Comment: No, I get a different expression. Numerically verifying, I believe your proposed solution is incorrect and the one Mathematica returns is correct.

Comment: @ChipHurst I have check my expected result for typos. It is correct. Do you obtain `2 \[Pi] BesselJ[0, 2 \[Pi] Sqrt[u^2 + v^2]]` ?

Comment: @ChipHurst why have you edited my question? The integral I want to calculate is $-i/v\oint_{\Gamma} exp[-2\pi i(xv+uy)]dx$ and $y=f(x)$.

Comment: To fix typos and formatting issues. (Feel free to revert anything of course.)

Comment: Let us take $(x,y)=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ in a circumference of unit radius, and $(u,v)=(\rho\cos\phi,\rho\sin\phi)$. Therefore my integral is $-i/v\int_0^{2\pi}\exp[-i \rho\cos(\theta-\phi)](-\sin\theta)d\theta$, and thus the result is $2\pi J_1(\rho)/\rho$. I still need a reason of why my solution is wrong and that of MMA is not.

Comment: Ah, I think this whole time you have been wanting to compute the [line integral with respect to $x$](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/LineIntegralsPtII.aspx)... and hence your $dx$ (my mistake for misunderstanding the notation :/). If that's the case, integrating over a 1D region in Mathematica computes the line integral with respect to *arc length* ($ds$ not $dx$). You'd have to manually parameterize the integral as you did above to compute it in Mathematica I believe. If this is where the discrepancy is, I'll delete my answer below and post this as the solution.

Comment: Good. Looking forward it. @ChipHurst I appreciate you have time to spend it in answering me.

Answer (score 2):

As I said in the comments, I believe Mathematica is correct and your proposed solution is not.

```
sol[u_, v_] = -I/v*Integrate[Exp[-2 π I (u*x + v*y)], {x, y} ∈ Circle[]] // FunctionExpand
```

[image]

We can test this solution and your solution v.s. numerical integration:

```
With[{u = 1, v = 2},
 {
  -I/v*NIntegrate[Exp[-2 π I (u*Cos[t] + v*Sin[t])], {t, 0, 2π}],
  sol[u, v],
  BesselJ[1, 2 π Sqrt[u^2 + v^2]]/Sqrt[u^2 + v^2]
 }
] // N // Chop
```

> ```
> {0. - 0.516032 I, 0. - 0.516032 I, 0.0631519}
> ```

Testing many random values:

```
(
 With[{u = #1, v = #2},
  {
   sol[u, v] + I/v*NIntegrate[Exp[-2 π I (u*Cos[t] + v*Sin[t])], {t, 0, 2π}],
   sol[u, v] - BesselJ[1, 2 π Sqrt[u^2 + v^2]]/Sqrt[u^2 + v^2]
  }
 ] // N // Chop
) & @@@ RandomReal[{0, 10}, {10, 2}]
```

> ```
> {{0, -0.0158981 + 2.76255 I},
>  {0, 0.0323925 - 0.345255 I},
>  {0, -0.112578 + 0.282299 I},
>  {0, -0.12562 - 0.183919 I},
>  {0, -0.0101141 + 0.128913 I},
>  {0, 0.0197579 + 0.0172606 I},
>  {0, -0.00352234 - 0.11468 I},
>  {0, 0.00125063 + 0.105634 I},
>  {0, 0.0148865 + 0.0448442 I},
>  {0, -0.00837518 - 0.0581776 I}}
> ```

Comment: That `I/v` looks out of place too since it makes the integrand non-symmetric to the exchange of `u` and `v`.  The proposed solution is symmetric.  But the proposed solution isn't good even if we remove the `I/v`.

Comment: My "written" solution above in a comment does not agree with MMA and with this.